# Certain row in GridView not firing RowCommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a very unusual problem with a GridView I have. At the moment there are a total of 4 rows, each with a LinkButton that fires event in the RowCommand method for that GridView. For 3 out of the 4 it works perfect, but with the 1 all it does is refresh the page - I've set a breakpoint right at the top of the RowCommand event, which breaks for every other row except that 1. I understand that without my code (I can't access it right this minute), you guys can't really help much but I just want to know if anyone else has experienced this?

Comment: how did you set the command? In a ButtonField, in your button with Template field... ?

Comment: Can you, for later readers, still add the relevant code, so we can understand the problem better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why, but a ModalPopupExtender seemed to cause this.

Comment: how did you solve this. I am hit with the same problem. Got the modal popUp and set targetcontrolId = popupcontrolId handing show and hide with the javascript